# jquery fadeIn (on)click each element in succession

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fade each element in a div to fadeIn (in) succession. I know how to fade in the whole block but not each individual div.

http://jsfiddle.net/reggi/Km55n/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#divWithDivs').fadeIn(500);
    }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fade the next div in the completion callback of the previous one.

For example:

```
function fadeAll(elems) {
    elems.filter(':hidden:first').fadeIn(1000, function() { fadeAll(elems); });
}

fadeAll($('#parent div'));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/Km55n/1/)
Note that you'll need to hide the children, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divWithDivs').children().first().fadeIn(500, function() {
        $(this).next().fadeIn(500, arguments.callee);
    });
```

Here the demo based on your: http://jsfiddle.net/Km55n/2/

Comment: He wants them to fade **sequentially**.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gft6c/3/):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var show_next = function(elem) {
        if (elem.length) {
            elem.fadeIn(300, function () {
                show_next(elem.next());
            });
        }
    };
    show_next($('div#divWithDivs').children().first()); 
});
```